# determine firefox profile of the current user

Tags: delphi

How can I find out with Delphi the profile name and folder of the firefox profile of the current user? Sometimes there are more than one firefox profile for the user within the `appdata\roaming` folder. So I would have to read the `profile.ini` file.

Can anybody help me with the Delphi code?

Andreas

Comment: Seems you already know the solution (read the INI file), so what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The Delphi console application below reads the Profiles.Ini file and writes the profile name and path from each [ProfileX] section to the console.  It's slightly long-winded,
but if you are not too familiar with working with Ini files in Delphi, it should show you how to get at what you want.  It should work fine in Lazarus, too.

```
program FirefoxProfiles;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, IniFiles;


procedure GetProfiles(IniFile : TIniFile; Sections, Profiles : TStringList);
var
  i,
  j : Integer;
  Find,
  SectionName,
  ProfileName : String;
  UserName : String;
begin
  UserName := GetEnvironmentVariable('UserName');

  IniFile.ReadSections(Sections);

  Find := 'Profile';
  for i := 0 to Sections.Count - 1 do begin
    SectionName := Sections[i];
    if CompareText('Profile', Copy(SectionName, 1, Length(Find))) = 0 then begin
      Profiles.Add(SectionName);
      writeln(ProfileName);
    end;
  end;


  for j := 0 to Profiles.Count - 1 do begin
    ProfileName := Profiles[j];
    writeln('Profile: ', ProfileName);
    writeln('Name: ', IniFile.ReadString(ProfileName, 'Name', ''));
    writeln('Path: ', IniFile.ReadString(ProfileName, 'Path', ''));
    writeln;
  end;
end;

var
  IniFile : TIniFile;
  Sections,
  Profiles : TStringList;
  i,
  j : Integer;
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create('c:\Users\ma\appdata\roaming\mozilla\firefox\profiles.ini');

  try
   Sections := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Profiles := TStringList.Create;
     try
       GetProfiles(IniFile, Sections, Profiles);
     finally
       Profiles.Free;
     end;
   finally
     Sections.Free;
   end;
  finally
    IniFile.Free;
    readln;
  end
end.
```

A potential problem is identifying the profile(s) of the current user.  The code above shows how to get the current UserName from the OS environment, but the UserName doesn't necessarily correspond to the `Name` value in any of the profiles.  F.i. in this laptop I have four profiles set up, but none of them has a `Name` the same as my OS UserName.  Obviously, if your situation *will* have a profile with the OS UserName, you could search for it by comparing it with the return value of `IniFile.ReadString(ProfileName, 'Name', '')`.

Comment: Ok, so what is it you still need to know beyond what I've put in the code?  I thought I'd answered your q as written ...

Comment: I know the username and that means I know the firefox profile directory of that user. Isn't it like this, that the current profile of the user is used in the profile.ini as .default?
What I want to do is to copy the firefox user bookmarks from an old PC to the firefox profil of a new PC. The problem I also find out that we have diffent version of firefox from 60 to 68 and that the firefox profile is not the same in all version.

Comment: I think those are really differerent technical points that require a separate q if you need help with them.  With my four profles, when I start FF I get a pop-up "Choose user profile" with one item highlighted/selected as the default.  The item is the one whose value in the one specified in the Default= section of the [InstallXYZ] section of Profiles.Ini; if I substitute the Path value from one of the other Profile sections, that becomes the pre-selected one.  Btw I've no idea where the XYZ value after [Install comes from.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try if it works. I want to create a general tool to copy bookmarks for some hundreds user's. And all of them have to change there PCs from Windows 7 to a new Windows 10 PC.

Comment: But you do realise that if a user creates a FF account, they can synchronize their bookmarks across any machines they use? This is already built into FF and doesn't require any Delphi code at all. See the Sync entry under `about:preferences`

Comment: Yes I know, but this is what we do not want (use any kind of cloud outside our network)

Comment: @Andreas: Go to "Bookmarks -> Show All Bookmarks" in FireFox then use the "Import and Backup" facility in there...

Comment: @HeartWare:  Thanks and good point, I'd forgotten about the Import/Export option.  Though I'm not sure how one would automate this given the scale of what the OP says he needs to do.  I was about to suggest copying the Sqlite file where I think these are stored.  Anyway, I think this is wandering rather far from the original q, myself.

Comment: That's why I made it a comment, and not an answer :-)

Comment: @HeartWare:  Wise move ;-)

Comment: I think this answered your q as originally posted, so would you be so kind as to accept it, please, by clicking the tick icon on its lhs.?